# Command line arguments order

Tags: command-line, arguments

Someone once told me there was a standard when it comes to parsing options on the command line. Something like:

```
./script.sh [options/flags] [command or file]
```

I understand that when parsing a shell script this makes life easier since you can `shift` through the flags and anything left can be accessed by `$@ or $*`, but is there an actual written standard?

Most programmes I've looked at follow this standard, but there are some exceptions, eg `ls` where `ls -l /path`, `ls /path -l` and `ls /path -l /path2` are all acceptable.

Comment: I think options after arguments is non-posix and `--` can be used to specify no further options to follow...

Comment: but they help, for ex: if I forgot an option, I can simply add it to the end from previous command

Comment: `ls Documents -l` will return the short form listing of the `Documents` folder along with the error `ls: -l: No such file or directory` on systems not using GNU `ls`.

Comment: Related: [Why does my ls --help not work?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/224451)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The POSIX Base Definitions has a section on "[Utility Conventions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html)" which applies to the POSIX base utilities.

The standard [`getopts`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getopts.html) utility and the [`getopt()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html) system interface ("C function") adheres to the guidelines (further down on the page linked to above) when parsing the command line in a shell script or C program. Specifically, for `getopts` (as an example):

> When the end of options is encountered, the `getopts` utility shall exit with a return value greater than zero; the shell variable `OPTIND` shall be set to the index of the first operand, or the value `"$#" +1` if there are no operands; the `name` variable shall be set to the  character. **Any of the following shall identify the end of options:** the first `--` argument that is not an option-argument, finding an argument that is not an option-argument and does not begin with a `-`, or encountering an error.

What this basically says is that options shall come first, and then operands (your "command or file").

Doing it any other way would render using `getopts` or `getopt()` impossible, and would additionally likely confuse users used to the POSIX way of specifying options and operands for a command.

Note that the abovementioned standard only applies to POSIX utilities, but as such it sets a precedence for Unix utilities in general.  Non-standard Unix utilities can choose to follow or to break this, obviously.

For example, the GNU coreutils, even though they implement the standard utilities, allows for things like

```
$ ls Documents/ -l
```

if the `POSIXLY_CORRECT` environment variable is not set, whereas the BSD version of the same utilities do not.

This has the consequence that the following works as expected (if you expect POSIX behaviour, that is) on a BSD system:

```
$ touch -- 'test' '-l'

$ ls -l test -l
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  kk  0 Jan 11 16:44 -l  
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  kk  0 Jan 11 16:44 test
```

But on a GNU coreutils system, you get

```
$ ls -l test -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 kk kk 0 Jan 11 16:44 test
```

However:

```
$ env POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 ls -l test -l
```

and

```
$ ls -l -- test -l
```

will do the "right" thing on a GNU system too.

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

- There is a [standard command line format](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_01).
- It requires options before arguments.
- That part of the standard is widely ignored.

## an example

All three of the option parsing libraries I have worked with in python *default* to allowing interspersed arguments and provide an illustration of what is common:

1. The now deprecated python standard library module [`optparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html) allows:

   ```
   OptionParser.enable_interspersed_args()
   ```

   > Set parsing to not stop on the first non-option, allowing interspersing switches with command arguments. This is the default behavior.
2. The current python standard library module [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) allows (and only allows) interspersed arguments.
3. `click`, the library I am currently favoring, allows [interspersed arguments to be disabled](http://click.pocoo.org/6/api/#click.Context.allow_interspersed_args):

   ```
   click.Context(allow_interspersed_args=False)
   ```

   But discusses this possibility in the advanced section under trouble shooting [unknown args to sub-commands](http://click.pocoo.org/6/advanced/#forwarding-unknown-options).

Comment: that is not an answer you can put that in comment, or explain little more further

Comment: The question is: Is there an actual written standard?  What did I miss?

Comment: The standard applies to the POSIX utilities, it's not a standard for all command-line tools in a POSIX-compliant system (although it is useful to know).